# php image file upload and html 5 demo using jquery / javascript using $.ajax OR $.post OR xmlHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, jquery, cordova

There are many posts on the similar topic but my situation is completely different.

I am using jquery library for a project and using phonegap to make it cross platform.
I have to provide an option for image upload which shall act in the following manner -
When a user selects an image, he shall be provided with an image demo on the screen. He shall be capable of changing the image.
After the image preview, user shall be able to enter other form details.
After filling the complete form, the entire data (along with image file) needs to be sent to the php backend file.

Till now, I am unable to successfully use the AJAX method for sending the file as well as data. Please suggest useful links or resources to create a solution consistent even with the phonegap library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps or works with PhoneGap and you might already be doing it, but this is what I use for AJAX uploads, using an iFrame fro transport:

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileTransfer.upload()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_upload). Here is a good tutorial on using it.

http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/